# Problema con el background

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema con respecto al *background* de la página web, que estoy terminando:

Me falta solamente sobreponer toda la parte del blog ENCIMA del *background* de matrix y que todo se vea bien y centrado.

Lamentablemente no he logrado concretarlo, he intentando con `FIXED` o `ABSOLUTE` y nada. También intenté con el `z-index` colocándole números y tampoco me funcionó.

He aquí el código:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  c.height = window.innerHeight;
  c.width = window.innerWidth;
  var txts = "{{site.bgtext}}";
  txts = txts.split("");
  var font_size = 12;
  var columns = c.width / font_size;
  var drops = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < columns; x++) drops[x] = 1;
  function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#490";
    ctx.font = font_size + "px arial";
    for (var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) {
      var text = txts[Math.floor(Math.random() * txts.length)];
      ctx.fillText(text, i * font_size, drops[i] * font_size);
      if (drops[i] * font_size > c.height || Math.random() > 0.98) drops[i] = 0;
      drops[i]++;
    }
  }
  setInterval(draw, 20);
```

```css
body {
    font-family: monospace;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 70px; 
}

#big-div {
    height: 400px;
    color: #34a507;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.matrix-bg {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

a {
    color:red;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}

.container2 {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Styles CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

    <title>Hacker blog!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
                <div class="matrix-bg">
                        <canvas id="c" height="700" width="1093"></canvas>
                </div>       

    <div id="big-div" style="background-color: transparent;">
    <div class="container0">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">/Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">/Email </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">/Github </a>
                    </li>

                  </ul>
                  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </nav>

        <h2>Hacker Personal Blog</h2>
    </div>


    <div class="container1">
        <h3>Working on...</h3>
        <table style="background-color: transparent;" class="table table-sm">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Projects</th>
                    <th scope="col">With</th>
                    <th scope="col">On</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Hacking Facebook</td>
                    <td>Marc Zuckerberg</td>
                    <td>Linux</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>Government</td>
                    <td>Donald Trump</td>
                    <td>Windows XP</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>Your Mom</td>
                    <td>Whatsapp</td>
                    <td>Fridays</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>

        <h5>Download and Documentation: <a href="#">Here</a> </h5>      
    </div>

    <div class="container2">
        <h3>Post list, dates and stuffs</h3>
        <ul style="background-color: transparent;" class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">amazing-hacking-project</a> Jul 16, 19</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">how_fb_makesyou_stupid</a> May 25, 19</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">the_rise_of_chicken_food</a> Apr 16, 19</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">yourmom-project-github</a> Feb 04, 19</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">your_sister_too-github</a> Jan 01, 19</li>
         </ul>
    </div>

        <footer>contact: luisjoselopezd@gmail.com</footer>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Como pueden observar en la ejecución del código con HTML, CSS, JS y Bootstrap se darán cuenta cuál es el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El canvas lo pones fixed ( top, right, bottom, left todos 0 ) y con z-index -1

Como failsafe para navegadores no muy estandar podes ponerle también:

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c');
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  c.height = window.innerHeight;
  c.width = window.innerWidth;
  var txts = "{{site.bgtext}}";
  txts = txts.split("");
  var font_size = 12;
  var columns = c.width / font_size;
  var drops = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < columns; x++) drops[x] = 1;
  function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#490";
    ctx.font = font_size + "px arial";
    for (var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) {
      var text = txts[Math.floor(Math.random() * txts.length)];
      ctx.fillText(text, i * font_size, drops[i] * font_size);
      if (drops[i] * font_size > c.height || Math.random() > 0.98) drops[i] = 0;
      drops[i]++;
    }
  }
  setInterval(draw, 20);
```

```css
body {
    font-family: monospace;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 70px; 
}

#big-div {
    height: 400px;
    color: #34a507;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.matrix-bg {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

a {
    color:red;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}

.container2 {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#c{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Styles CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

    <title>Hacker blog!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
                <div class="matrix-bg">
                        <canvas id="c" height="700" width="1093"></canvas>
                </div>       

    <div id="big-div" style="background-color: transparent;">
    <div class="container0">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">/Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">/Email </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">/Github </a>
                    </li>

                  </ul>
                  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </nav>

        <h2>Hacker Personal Blog</h2>
    </div>


    <div class="container1">
        <h3>Working on...</h3>
        <table style="background-color: transparent;" class="table table-sm">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Projects</th>
                    <th scope="col">With</th>
                    <th scope="col">On</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Hacking Facebook</td>
                    <td>Marc Zuckerberg</td>
                    <td>Linux</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>Government</td>
                    <td>Donald Trump</td>
                    <td>Windows XP</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>Your Mom</td>
                    <td>Whatsapp</td>
                    <td>Fridays</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>

        <h5>Download and Documentation: <a href="#">Here</a> </h5>      
    </div>

    <div class="container2">
        <h3>Post list, dates and stuffs</h3>
        <ul style="background-color: transparent;" class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">amazing-hacking-project</a> Jul 16, 19</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">how_fb_makesyou_stupid</a> May 25, 19</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">the_rise_of_chicken_food</a> Apr 16, 19</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">yourmom-project-github</a> Feb 04, 19</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">your_sister_too-github</a> Jan 01, 19</li>
         </ul>
    </div>

        <footer>contact: luisjoselopezd@gmail.com</footer>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: FUNCIONO SEÑORES!!! Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: la cuchara no existe! =P